# MVC Ajax Request not triggering in controller when submitting request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am new to the this and not sure why it's not reaching my controller. I enter an ID and nothing happens, my breakpoint in the controller isn't hit. Did I miss something?

CONTROLLER ~/Controllers/AppointmentController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Schedule(int id = 0)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                Customer customer = _customerRepository.Find(id);
                return PartialView("Schedule", customer); 
            }
            return View();
        }
```

VIEW ~/Views/Appointment/Schedule.cshtml

```
@model Customer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Schedule";
}

<h2>Schedule</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Schedule", "Appointment",
    new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "Customer"
}))
{
    <label>ID Search</label>
    <input type="search" name="customerSearch" placeholder="ID" />
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
}
<div id="Customer">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Customer/_Customers.cshtml", Model)
</div>
```

Comment: Did you set the reference to jquery or jquery unobtrusive?

Comment: That and did you take a look at javascript console in whatever browser you're using to see if there are any JS errors occuring? Also, if using Chrome use Network tab in developer tools to see that post is being done and what result it's getting back (or use Fiddler to monitor requests).

Comment: Unobtrusive is set to false in the Web.Config and removed from the Script bundles. There is no errors in the console, It seems like it's just doing a regular submit with a full page reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the Action labelled with [HttpPost].

This will work fine on the AJAX request with the POST HttpMethod, but the initial page load will be a GET Request - try removing the [HttpPost] or restructuring so that you have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Schedule(int id = 0, string customerSearch = "")
    {
        Customer customer = _customerRepository.Find(id);
        return PartialView("Schedule", customer); 
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Schedule(int id = 0)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Also, your AJAX form is not posting from an input with name="id", so that will need to be addressed.

Comment: Thank you! The issue was with my id variable. I changed it to customerSearch like you suggested and it worked! :D